# I/O in Pytorch DataLoader with np.load extremely slow on SSD

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, pytorch, solid-state-drive

I am trying to load a relatively large batch of float16 multispectral images (BxCxHxW=800x12x256x256) to train a deep learning model. The code for the DataLoader is extremely simple:

```
import torch
import os

paths = os.listdir("/home/bla/data")
class MultiSpectralImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, paths):
        self.paths = np.array(self.paths)
        self.l = len(self.paths)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.l

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.paths[idx]
        image = np.load(path)
        return image

dataset = MultiSpectralImageDataset(paths)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=800, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=16, drop_last=True)

for i, X in enumerate(loader):
    X = X.cuda(non_blocking=True).float()
```

The images are individual files on a very fast NVME SSD. I can verify the read speed of the SSD with `sudo hdparm -tT /dev/nvme1n1`. This gives me:

```
/dev/nvme1n1:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 geometry      = 1907729/64/32, sectors = 3907029168, start = 0
bla@bla:~/workspace$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/nvme1n1

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing cached reads:   59938 MB in  2.00 seconds = 30041.04 MB/sec
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Timing buffered disk reads: 6308 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2102.35 MB/sec
```

This confirms the read speed of the SSD is over 2GB/s. However, when using PyTorch DataLoader, I am not nearly able to match this IO speed. During training, the GPU is idle (0% utilization) most of the time, and the CPU is hardly used (`htop` shows most cores at 0% usage, some cores at at 0.5-1.5% usage). Running `iotop` shows

[image: iotop shows read speed]

The Total Disk Read speed never surpasses 300MB/s. If I decrease `num_workers` (say by half), the Total Disk Read emains the same (~200MB/s), and each individual thread doubles in read speed. In particular, I observe that every `num_workers` iterations, the iteration is extremely slow (takes ~1 minute). This apparently simply means that the loading from disk is too slow, as discussed [in the PyTorch forum here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/data-loader-takes-a-lot-of-time-for-every-nth-iteration/10831)

What's weird is that I am 99.9% confident it used to work. I remember constistently reaching almost 100% GPU utilization with the same data-loading procedure.

Things I've tried, but with no successs:

- Updating Ubuntu, updating everything with `apt udpate` & `upgrade`, rebooting, powering off and restarting
- Updating the SSD firmware using `fwupd` (no updates available)
- Giving higher priority to the process by running Python using `sudo` and using `os.nice(-10)`
- Making space on the SSD (30% of the storage is empty, I have run `fstrim -v`.
- Using memmap, i.e. using the keyword in `np.load(path, memmap_mode='r')`

I really appreciate any help, as I've been stuck with this problem for weeks now, and what used to take 13 minutes per epoch now takes approximately 1h45 per epoch, making things infeasible to train.

Comment: Hi, I'm running in a similar problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Not exactly sure why this helped, but I was able to resolve it by moving all my data to another hard drive, and then moving it back to the original hard drive.